# Javascript event in a wrapper function for a html element

Tags: javascript, html, events, iife

I have the following issue:
Let's say in my html page i have the following element:

```
<button onclick="myfunction(id)">Save</button>
```

and in my javascript file

```
(function(){

   function myfunction(id){
     // magic happends
   };

})();
```

In this case it's not going to work because the myfunction is wrapped in the iife function, so my question is: **Is there a best practice in which you can keep your JavaScript logic inside a wrapper function and in the same time to be accessible to the HTML elments ?**

Comment: @rpl This is purely example code which ***does not*** belong at Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a best practice in which you can keep your JavaScript logic inside a wrapper function and in the same time to be accessible to the HTML elments ?

Depending on the structure of your app, the best way would be to not use inline event handlers but use the DOM API to bind the handler:

```
(function(){

   function myfunction(id){
     // magic happends
   };

   button.addEventListener('click', myfunction);
})();
```

[More information about event handling.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

If that's not possible and you really need to use inline event handlers, you can always make the function global:

```
(function(){

   window.myfunction = function myfunction(id){
     // magic happends
   };

})();
```

Comment: Adding event listeners is definitely the way to go; you get more flexibility, better separation of concerns, and you don't have to expose loads of globals. You can also do stuff like remove event listeners, or add them conditionally.